# Rest Api Create a resource design

Tags: web-services, rest

I have a rest service and on that I want to add an attribute for each object I have it. So I have player objects and I want to add their games' statistics after each game.

My endpoint to get all players is;

```
GET /api/players
```

and I have a game object in which there is a player id; so is it ok if I develop a service without indicating player id on the link as the object has already have it;

```
POST /api/players/game [gameObject]
```

or should I put id to the link as well

```
POST /api/player/{playerID}/game [gameObject]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of them are perfectly fine. It is a matter of how descriptive you can be with your URLs.

Personally I would prefer the second URL because it is easier to comprehend and in the first look it is clear that the `game object` is meant for a particular player.

**READ:**
[Best Practices for Designing a Pragmatic RESTful API](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#restful)